# print to PDF each layer separately from a PCB schematics in Altium

Tags: altium

I designed a PCB with Altium and now I want to print each layer separately in one or several PDF files.

From the Porjects tab I selected the *.PcbDoc => File => Smart PDF...

In the window "Choose Export Target" I select the .PrjPcb file and in the following window too.

In the window "Export Bill of Materials", I do not export the bill of materials.
In the window "PCB Printout Settings" I select Top, Bottom, Double Sided and Holes check boxes. I also select the "Entire Sheet" Area to print

In the window "Additional PDF Settings" I chose to print in color and all the check boxes in the Additional Information section excepted "Global Bookmarks for Components and Nets".

Finally I let all suggested by default in the "Final Steps" window.

And when I click on finish the resulting PDF is my PCB with all the layers in one page, so it is not readable...

I am using Altium 14.3.

Comment: Did you take a look at "Output Jobs" (.OutJob)? Or is this not availible in 14.3?

Comment: In the .OutbJob there is a Documentation Outputs section where there is a PCB Prints file. Next to it there is a sub window "Output Containers" in which there is "PDF", 3Folder Structure" and "Video" but in none of those files I find what I'm looking for...

Comment: All else failing, export Gerbers. Then print to PDF from a standalone Gerber viewer. (This is often worth doing anyway to check the Gerber export process does exactly what you expect)

Comment: You'll soon discover that "Smart PDF" is really retarded. I use one of the post processing steps - Output Job (even for schematics since Smart PDF messes up) or Draftsman.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an .OutJob; create a new Output Job and then:

In "Outputs" -> "Documentation Outputs" -> "PCB Prints": add a single PrintOut for each layer and for each PrintOut add the layers you want:

[image]

Output Container is PDF.
If you want color and not just gray, you have to right click on "PCB Prints" and open the "Page Setup...".

Comment: I'll try it, I think this will solve my issue. I keep you informed

Comment: @RPerun Did it solve your issue?

Comment: This method does work, although I can't figure out how to get the layers to print in colour instead of black and white. I tried to "Retrieve colours from PCB doc" but that still gave an output in B/W.

Comment: @SM32 In older versions right-click on "PCB Prints" in .OutJob file and click on page setup. There is a button called "Color". In newer versions this button is directly in the configure-menu of "PCB Prints".